# Can't iMessage with a Samsung Phone

Tags: messages, ipad

I am having trouble using iMessage with one of my contacts.  I can send messages to iPhones without any issues.  My contact's phone is a Samsung Galaxy S3.  Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 5):

iMessage only works between apple devices. If you were using an iPhone it would be able to use SMS instead of iMessage when the other person has a non iOS device, but since you are using an iPad you can't contact them.

Comment: If you want to be able to message people on non-Apple devices from your iPad, you might want to try to get your contact to use a cross-platform service like WhatsApp or Facebook Messenger.

Answer (score 1):

It's because iMessage only works through Apple devices;  not other companies text messaging

Answer (score 0):

### You can SMS from iPad to any mobile device that supports SMS

- create [Google Account](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail)
- enable [Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice) free account and set up your Google Voice number
- download and install [Google Voice](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-voice/id318698524) - iPhone app, looks ugly, so you may want to:
- enable [Text message to email](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/160203?hl=en)
- enable [Google Voice Voicemail](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115986?hl=en)
- enable [Google Voice Voicemail Transcriptions](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115986?hl=en) and while doing that, also:
- enable eMail Delivery of Voicemail Transcriptions: Next to "Voicemail Notifications", check the box next to eMail the message to and select an eMail address to receive your voicemail transcriptions via email
- sync your [contacts with Google](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4872)

Now you can either use the Google Voice app for SMS, or Apple Mail, once first receiving an SMS, just reply like its an eMail. Messages longer than 166 characters get truncated rather turning into 2 SMS messages for eMailing SMS delivery only (the app behavior is different).

Comment: Footnote: Google Voice is only available to people who can tie the Google Voice number to a phone number based in the US.

Comment: Where else would you want to? jk! Very good point.